# Dynamic updating of Events Layers created from XY Data in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, table, events, ms-access

I have an Access database table that I am dumping data into, and I created an Events layer from that, but I have and will continue to update the table. I updated the table and created a new Events Layer to try and compare two event layers, but my data is too large to determine one way or another.

It appears that my tables are updating to reflect the changes from my Access db, but the Events Layer does not contain the update.

Is it possible to have the Events layer update with the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the MXD and opening will update the Events Layer. Also, I believe zooming to extent has worked as it causes ArcMap to redraw the layer. This was not initially noticed due to size of data and time it takes to draw very large files.